# Как уменьшить количество вызовов классов?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Всем доброго времени суток.

С недавних пор работаю авто-тестировщиком, пишу тесты на java и selenium webdriver, в процессе изучения того и другого.
В данный момент у меня возник вопрос ответ на который мне в данный момент совершенно неочевиден, а проблема стоит остро и в дальнейшем неизбежно будет прогрессировать… очень прошу помочь с решением.

Я написал что-то вроде надстройки над селениумом, которая выглядит следующим образом:
есть класс Element который определяет наличие элемента или нескольких на странице, а так же некоторых их свойств
от него наследуются классы типа Tools (каждый из которых содержит методы для работы с определенными элементами), затем их все собирает через композицию еще один класс, и от него уже наследуются все классы отождествляемые с непосредственно вебстраницами которые я тестирую.

Иерархически схема в данный момент выглядит так:

```
class A
class B extends A
class C extends B
class Buttons extends C
class Breadcrumbs extends C
class Table extends C
```

…
class Page собирает все что после C (там около полутора десятка элементов каждому из которых посвящен отдельный класс)
и от Page как раз наследуются все тестируемые “страницы”.

В данный момент все отлично работает (с точки зрения затраченного на тесты времени), но… я поместил в конструктор каждого класса код вида System.out.println(“init classname”); и ужаснулся количеству инициализаций этих классов, сообщений об инициализации в консоли больше трех десятков. :frowning:

С ростом кода во вспомогательных страницах а так же с количеством тестов или тестируемых страниц мне кажется что вся эта конструкция грозит неоправданным расходом ресурсов тестовой машины, или дикими тормозами при прогонах.

У меня устойчивое ощущение что я что-то делаю не так, и что количество инициализаций можно значительно сократить или вообще свести к одному-единственному.
Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно для этого сделать? Буду рад любым предложениям или советам.

Теоретически неплохим решением проблемы выглядит паттерн Singleton, но слышал от некоторых людей что конкретно для селениума статический вебдрайвер не лучший выход из положения - мешает многопоточности и в целом выглядит как какой-то хак.
С другой стороны буду признателен если меня в этой позиции разубедят. :)

Comment: Не делайте System.out.println в конструкторах и спите спокойно. А то, рано или поздно, дойдёте до оптимизации вызовов методов из методов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть такая вещь в нашем не легком деле, как "преждевременная оптимизация". Вы пытаетесь на старте уже решать проблемы производительности, хотя никаких проблем на данный момент нет. Мой Вам совет, бросьте это дело и не забивайте себе голову. Пишите код дальше. Такие вещи, как инициализация классов, размер heap-а, работа GarbageCollector-а и прочие "кишки" jvm на старте приходится обдумывать и решать, когда вы пишите софт под заведомо слабые железки (холодильники, телевизоры и прочая техника), либо Ваш софт уже уперся в производительность, и нужно выжимать максимум из текущего железа. Советую почитать "Чистый код" Боба Мартина, и "Совершенный код" Макконелла.